# mysql Check if user is in time period (where null exisit)

Tags: mysql, timestamp

```
In                    Name            Out
2017-01-01 10:00:00   Sam             2017-01-01 17:00:00
2017-01-18 10:00:00   James           2017-01-18 12:00:00
2017-01-18 10:00:00   John            NULL          -> means still in office
```

How do I find all people who is in office at 2017-01-18 11:00:00 only for example?

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE '2017-01-08 11:00:00' BETWEEN IN AND OUT
```

-> This only returns James. (should be James and John)

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE '2017-01-08 11:00:00' BETWEEN IN AND NOW()
```

-> This returns Sam, James, John (should be James and John only)

Anyone can help? Somehow a I need to replace NULL (Out) Column with current timestamp. But using NOW() causes a problem for the BETWEEN statement.

Comment: In is a poor name for a column btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE '2017-01-18 11:00:00' BETWEEN `IN` AND COALESCE(`OUT`, NOW())
```

The query uses [**COALESCE**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to replace a `NULL` value in column `OUT` with the current date/time value.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce121/3)